# Small Miniconda, Keras, and TensorFlow in Docker

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

We are deploying docker containers into production that use Keras for machine learning models. So according to Keras and TensorFlow documentation, we need to have Anaconda with Python 3.6 (not 3.7) and the two python packages keras and tensorflow.

So in our dockerfile we install the latest version of Python that is below 3.7 (so 3.6.8) by installing the latest Miniconda which is Python 3.7, and then downgrading to Python 3.6.8:

```
RUN wget --quiet https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.12-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh && \
    /bin/bash ~/miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/conda && \
    rm ~/miniconda.sh && \
    /opt/conda/bin/conda clean -tipsy && \
    ln -s /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /etc/profile.d/conda.sh && \
    echo ". /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    echo "conda activate base" >> ~/.bashrc
ENV PATH /opt/conda/bin:$PATH

RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda install python=3.6.8
```

We then install the python libraries needed:

```
RUN /opt/conda/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir keras tensorflow
```

This ends up being massive:
  * Miniconda is ~250mb
  * Downgrading to python 3.6.8 adds ~200mb
  * The python packages add ~600mb

Are there ways to make this lighter? It *feels* like there should be some sort of lightweight version of TensorFlow and Keras for when you only want to run models, not train them. It also seems like there should be a way to clean up the python downgrade to remove some no longer needed files.

**Update**
To clarify, this is part of a [larger docker container](https://github.com/tmobile/r-tensorflow-api), so using the prebuilt tensorflow/tensorflow isn't an option.

Comment: What size is manageable for this particular server? E.g., what is NOT massive? What can you tolerate?

Comment: Do you need miniconda specifically? Asking since you are pip installing tf and keras. If not, perhaps look at using Python:3.6.8-slim as your base image.

Comment: These documents for [Tensorflow Docker][1] don't say anything about requiring conda. Can you please link the documentation that you refer to? 


  [1]: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker

Comment: Scott--we are hoping for under 2gb, but since we install a bunch of other things to the container (mainly R and R packages), we don't have a hard rule on that

Comment: Weird, I thought at one point the tensorflow documentation said anaconda was required, but when I look at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip I don't see it needed. That might shave size off the installation.

Comment: Actually I just realized the anaconda requirement came from RStudio Keras, not Keras or TensorFlow itself: https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/install_keras.html

Comment: With the latest TensorFlow 1.13.1 you can install it on python 3.7

Answer (score 2):

The latest non-GPU version of the tensorflow docker image should be about 444 MB as of this writing (looking at the [current tags](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/tags)).

> latest 444 MB
>
> Last update: 4 hours ago

There are 578 tags, but I didn't see any smaller than 400 MB. As for [Keras](https://keras.io/#installation), I am pretty sure that it is installed with TensorFlow these days so you should be good to go.

> Before installing Keras, please install one of its backend engines:
> TensorFlow, Theano, or CNTK. We recommend the TensorFlow backend.

To install the latest TensorFlow Docker image I just visited the [DockerHub page](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/) and ran:

```
docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow
```

Comment: This doesn't resolve my problem since the docker container is being built from a different image currently.

Comment: Ok. Does that warrant the downvote? I have asked for the docs you're referring to and was trying to help :-)

Comment: I assumed not an answering I was looking for should be downvoted? I tried to undo but it won't let me...

Comment: The docker file that generated the 444 MB image is a good reference of what to include and keep the space down: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/dockerfiles/dockerfiles/cpu.Dockerfile